# JUnit4Provider Does Not Work

Tags: tycho

I'm trying to get project with the packaging type `eclipse-test-plugin` to work (I have the ambitious goal to get it to execute tests someday, but right now there are only two classes with empty tests methods inside).

I assume the problem only exists because we use a target configuration file, so needed plug-ins (or whatever) get not loaded automatically. In the absence of an up-to-date documentation or examples I guessed that the *pom.xml* for such a use case should look something like that:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${see.below}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <providerHint>junit4</providerHint>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*(Because without the dependency I got a `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider`, and that's where the class resides.)*

Now if I use the version 2.18.1 or below of the `surefire-junit4`, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file C:\workspaces\workspace\org.acme.project.rxp-build\org.acme.project.rxp.it\target\work\data\.metadata\.log.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.22.0:test (default-test) on project org.acme.project.rxp.it: An unexpected error occured while launching the test runtime (return code 13). See log for details. -> [Help 1]
```

Aaand the log file in question contains:

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.loadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:251)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireReflector.instantiateProvider(SurefireReflector.java:235)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.createProvider(ProviderFactory.java:113)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:78)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:91)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
```

If I use version `2.19` of the `surefire-junit4`, I get the following message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (test) on project org.acme.project.rxp.it: Execution test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.surefire.providerapi.ProviderParameters.isInsideFork()Z
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.createProviderInCurrentClassloader(ForkedBooter.java:230)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:199)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.surefire.providerapi.ProviderParameters.isInsideFork()Z
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.<init>(JUnit4Provider.java:103)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
```

I was a bit suspicious that `surefire-api` and `surefire-junit4` had the same version, so I made sure that Maven loads the same versions for both, but there was no change in the behavior.

What's the problem here? How do I get the test plug-in to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it works without stupid Maven dependencies if the target platform file contains

```
<unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
```

and the *Manifest.MF* contains

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime,
 org.junit
```

Answer (score -1):

up-to-date documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php

mentions working examples: http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/

Comment: You're right, I should have mentioned that I'm using a target definition file, which is talked about in the documentation for [half a paragraph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_files), but then not used anywhere.

Comment: not used anywhere? http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp/mars

Comment: Are you trying to help or making a point? Because I can't find the integration test project in this example.